# Recuperar objeto insertado en una base de datos con FastAPI y SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

Tengo el siguiente código que inserta un registro a una base de datos:

```py
@router.post('/{tipo}')
async def save_plantilla(tipo : str, request : Request, db : Session = Depends(deps.get_db), payload : dict = Depends(deps.get_payload)):
    adHoc : dict = await request.json()
    aux = {}
    c = json.loads(adHoc["items"])
    aux = AdHocs()
    aux.datos = c["datos"]
    # si está definido idAdHoc = eliminar elemento antiguo y crear uno nuevo
    if "idAdHoc" in c:
        aux.idAdHoc = c["idAdHoc"]
        db.query( AdHocs ).filter_by(idAdHoc=aux.idAdHoc).delete()
    aux.tipo = tipo
    db.add_all( [aux] )
    db.commit()
    return
```

El registro de la base de datos tiene un campo `id` que es `auto_increment`. ¿Puedo recuperar ese `id` en la misma función?

Comment: ¿Estás queriendo obtener el id del objeto que acabás de insertar?

Comment: @padaleiana Sí, lo equivalente a `LAST_INSERT_ID` de MySQL pero en sqlalchemy.